# Install rpm packages within a .tar.gz file from url in linux

Tags: software-installation, yum, rpm

I need to install few RPM files within a `TeradataToolsAndUtilitiesBase__linux_x8664.17.00.31.00.tar.gz` from
URL below and the file name is "TTU 17.10.11.00 Linux - Base"
https://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/teradata-tools-and-utilities-linux-installation-package-0

how can we do install by using command line by using either yum or rpm.

Answer (score 0):

You download the tar.gz (e.g. using your browser or `wget`), and then you extract it (`tar xf "Filename of.tar.gz"`), and then you install using `yum localinstall filename1.rpm filename2.rpm`.

Comment: we can do this way but I wanted to do this in one linux command as I am installing in a remote machine/server so wanted use one single command to do all these

Comment: there's no single command. Why would you expect there is?

Comment: we wanted to use one single command in the repos(ex:puppet) so it can install this software across all our machines. we are using your suggested method currently but its a manaul step. If there is no way to do this then we keep our current process. Thanks

Comment: puppet makes executing multiple commands consistently abundantly easy, that's the whole point of puppet.